# TableView does not reload data

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I am simply trying reload a TableView with new items pulled from an array and the tableView does not reload the new items. Here is the code. Any help please?
    import UIKit

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

        @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

        @IBAction func reloadData(sender: UIButton) {
            tableData = newItems
            self.tableViewController.tableView.reloadData()
        }

        var items = ["AAA", "BBB"]
        var newItems = ["XXX", "YYY"]

        var tableData = [String]()

        var tableViewController = UITableViewController(style: .Plain)

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            tableData = items
            var tableView = tableViewController.tableView
            tableView.dataSource = self
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        }


        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return tableData.count
        }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)as UITableViewCell
            cell.textLabel?.text = self.tableData[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you set a delegate to your tableView? `tableView.delegate = self` ?

Comment: Bad setup. You have tableViewController, but the tableView itself is referenced in your ViewController and datasource and delegate is provided here. Why do you have the tableViewController at all? You call reloadData on the tableView of that TableViewController, not myTableView that your refer to here. Datasource is also set on tableViewController.tableView, not myTableView..

Comment: Hi mikle90, I have inserted tableView.delegate = self in the viewDidLoad function but it still did not show the new data

Answer (score 1):

There are many mistakes in your code and here is your complete working code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

    var items = ["AAA", "BBB"]
    var newItems = ["XXX", "YYY"]

    var tableData = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableData = items
        myTableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

        myTableView.delegate = self
        myTableView.dataSource = self


    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

        return tableData.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        var cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = tableData[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    @IBAction func reloadData(sender: AnyObject) {

        tableData = newItems
        self.myTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Compare your code with this code and you will understand what you have done wrong.

[HERE](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=31863192866979115405) is sample project for more info.

Comment: Thanks Dharmesh. I get a syntax error in your code with: var cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell

Comment: Did you check my sample project?

Comment: Deleting the exclamation mark (!) removes the syntax error but the program crashes.

Comment: can you share your sample project?

Comment: Hi Dharmesh, link to the project shared on DropBox

Comment: Here is your working project: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=81907633851433436748

Comment: You are getting this error because you tableview was not installed from attribute inspector.

Comment: Accept answer if it helps..:)

Comment: Dear Dharmesh, I am not sure what you mean by:  tableview was not installed from attribute inspector. Kindly explain.

Comment: I have modified your project just test it.

Comment: The ! in the following: as! UITableViewCell gives me a syntax error. If I remove it, the syntax error disappears but the program crashes????

Comment: I suggest you to follow some basic tutorials about tableview. And it will help you a lot to understand your problem.. :)

Answer (score 0):

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!
var flag=1
var items = ["AAA", "BBB"]
var newItems = ["XXX", "YYY"]

var tableData = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if flag==1{
        tableData = items
    }
    myTableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    myTableView.delegate = self
    myTableView.dataSource = self
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

    return tableData.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    var cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = tableData[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

@IBAction func reloadData(sender: AnyObject) {
    if flag==1{
        tableData = items
        flag=0
    }else
    {
        tableData=newItems
        flag=1
    }
    self.myTableView.reloadData()
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,     UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!
    //var flag=1
    var items = ["AAA", "BBB"]
    var newItems = ["XXX", "YYY"]
    var tableData = String
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       // if flag==1{
      //      tableData = items
      // }
        myTableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        myTableView.delegate = self
        myTableView.dataSource = self
    }
```

`func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return tableData.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    var cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = tableData[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

@IBAction func reloadData(sender: AnyObject) {
   // if flag==1{
  //      tableData = items
   //     flag=0
   // }else
  //  {
  //      tableData=newItems
  //      flag=1
  //  }
    self.myTableView.reloadData()
}`

}